# Problems with long input/output in C

Tags: c, loops, input, output

I have to make a program in C that gets a non-defined amount of double values and prints them all increased by a certain percentage based on the number. The program should stop when the user enters a negative value. It all works well when I use a small quantity of numbers, but when the input consists of a larger amount of numbers the program prints just the last ones.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 double ins=0; //the input

 while(ins>=0){

    scanf("%lf",&ins);
    if(ins<0){break;}
    else{

        if(ins<500){printf("%.2lf ",ins*1.15);}
        else if(ins<=1000){printf("%.2lf ",ins*1.10);}
        else {printf("%.2lf ",ins*1.05);}


         }

 }



   return 0;
}
```

Additional information: Using GCC compiler.

Example of output the program should give for a specific input.

```
    Input:               

4003.31 1212.35 3414.31
4257.1 1394.37 1217.28
3602.85 4218.58 4994.8
1133.82 1086.48 2117.43
2253.86 3827.71 2170.16
1161.27 3069.77 1338.08
2791.99 3709.33 180.43
4555.77 318.58 1912.24
158.68 2106.49 4439.56
1247.34 -0.79

    Output I should get:
4203.48 1272.97 3585.03 4469.96
1464.09 1278.14 3782.99 4429.51
5244.54 1190.51 1140.80 2223.30
2366.55 4019.10 2278.67 1219.33
3223.26 1404.98 2931.59 3894.80
207.49 4783.56 366.37 2007.85 182.48
2211.81 4661.54 1309.71
```

What could I do to make the program work correctly not just with small amounts but also with quantities like the above ?

Edit: the output I'm getting with the above input is "1309.71",which is just the last number of the full output I should receive.

Comment: `but when the input consists of a larger amount of numbers the program prints just the last ones` - your problem is not totally understandable / clear to me. Can you provide the output you are currently getting?

Comment: Just the last number of the full output I should receive. In this case 1309.71

Comment: have you tried using a debugger - so that you can find out where the inputs have gone missing? because the code is not so big, it should not be very difficult to find that out.

Comment: in my case, the code seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out the solution. As you guys said that the code was working properly for you I tested it using another command line interface. And now the output is correct, so it seems like the one I was using before (Windows CMD) was deleting outputted information when that information reached a certain limit, maybe a small buffer size or something like that. Thank you for the help guys !!

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (yes, you can answer your own question - you just won't get any reputation for that).

Answer (score 2):

Note: You have a simple logic error. Because you are checking ins<500 before ins<=100 you can never hit the ins<=100 case.

Your code and sample data works for me. Can you give a more detailed description of the problem?

Comment: How does it answers the OP question? It should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @AlexLop. probably he answered it like this because he doesn't have enough reputation to comment in the question.

Comment: Yeah, I'm new here. I can only comment on my own answers.

Comment: The "logic error" was actually a mistake I made when I wrote the question. It should be "1000" instead of "100". The problem is that when I run the code and enter the sample input the only output is the last number of the output I should get.